# SQL - Which query will be more efficient?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

-Assume sample records whats to show CompanyName ,CompanyID ,OrderID , Ordername ,Sum(Amount) .Except amount all columns are Varchar

```
CompanyName  | CompanyID  | OrderID    |  OrderName    |      Amount
CS           |    10      |  5567      |  Bonds        |      67000
CS           |    10      |  5567      |  Bonds        |      77000
CS           |    10      |  5566      |  Derivatives  |      90000
Barleys      |    20      |  5567      |  Bonds        |      90000
Barleys      |    20      |  5566      |  Derivatives  |      90000
T.D          |    30      |  5566      |  Derivatives  |      90000
T.D          |    30      |  5567      |  Bonds        |      60000
```

Which query will be efficient

```
Select CompanyName, CompanyID, OrderID, OrderName ,Sum(Amount)
from @Table 
group by CompanyName, CompanyID, OrderID, OrderName;
```

Or:

```
Select  CompanyID, Max(CompanyName),OrderID, Max(OrderName) ,Sum(Amount)
from @Table
group by  CompanyID, OrderID;
```

Both Query gives the same result but what’s to know which query is good in terms of performance wise if the table contains more than 7 million records. will the group by affect the performance  ?

Comment: 1k is a trivial amount of records.  The first probably is probably very marginally better, but it makes no difference on such a small volume of data.

Comment: Compare plans of both queries and you will see which one performs better on your database

Comment: Sorry more than 2 Lakhs records @GordonLinoff

Comment: 2 Lakhs is also not very much data

Comment: In my opinion, the second may be somehow a little bit faster, because it needs to do fewer comparisons and use less temp space(if it goes to temp). But this is only at intuition level.

Comment: Im not sure about production records amount..just u can assume total amount records when u need to optimize...@sagi

Comment: Check the execution plans

Comment: You might want to read [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert, which points out lots of issues with this sort of question.